# Error in Linq - Unable To Translate into Store Expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to run a `Linq` and it throws an exception stating:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ECommerceApp.Models.CategoryList] CategoryDetails()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The following is the defined class:

```
public class ProductDetails : Products
{
   public string ParentCatName { get; set; }
   public string ChildCatName { get; set; }
   public string ImagePath { get; set; }
   public List<CategoryList> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryList
{
   public string Category { get; set; }
   public string SubCategory { get; set; }
   public string ParentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

I've to show all the categories in a home page and hence, defined list of categories in the class. The following is the `Linq`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = (from c in db.Products
                  select new ProductDetails
                  {
                     ProductName = c.ProductName,
                     Price = c.Price,
                     Categories = CategoryDetails() //Throws exception here and I tried to convert it to ToList() but doesn't work
                  }).ToList();

     return View(result);
}

public List<CategoryList> CategoryDetails()
{
    List<CategoryList> result = aGateway.GetAllCategories().ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Finally in the view, I tried to access the category details as follows with `foreach` loop:

```
 @item.Categories[0].Category
 @item.Categories[0].SubCategory
 @item.Categories[0].ParentCategory
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: So every product just has the same list of all categories assigned?

Comment: have you tried doing directly Categories = aGateway.GetAllCategories().ToList()?

Comment: Actually not and they are defined individually. But my requirement is to show all the categories and sub-categories in a sidebar @Equalsk.

Comment: Yes, I tried it already, doesn't work @gnsanty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
  var result = (from c in db.Products
                  select new ProductDetails
                  {
                     ProductName = c.ProductName,
                     Price = c.Price,
                     Categories = null 
                  }).ToList();
 foreach (var c in result)
     {
       c.Categories= CategoryDetails();
     }
     return View(result);
```

If that doesn't work, define the class of result, and don't assign the categories attribute inside the linq query

Comment: Worked perfectly @gnsanty. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The query side of your expression isn't aware of the `CategoryDetails()` function you have available.

[A similar issue with suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970100/calling-a-method-inside-a-linq-query)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like fetching the categories first outside the query and store them in a collection, then assign the collection to the newly created ProductDetails

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var cats = CategoryDetails();
    var result = (from c in db.Products
                  select new ProductDetails
                  {
                     ProductName = c.ProductName,
                     Price = c.Price,
                     Categories = cats 
                  }).ToList();

     return View(result);
}

public List<CategoryList> CategoryDetails()
{
    List<CategoryList> result = aGateway.GetAllCategories().ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[gnsanty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46814637/209259) answer works, but if you're using linq, there is no reason in this case to use a foreach statement:

```
var result = (from c in db.Products
              select new ProductDetails
              {
                 ProductName = c.ProductName,
                 Price = c.Price,
                 Categories = null 
              })
  .ToList()  // Execute the query before updating the property
  .Select(pd => {
    pd.Categories = CategoryDetails();
    return pd;
  })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks @Erik Philips. I really appreciate your answer and just run it.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with gnsanty's answer, I just prefer to stay in linq statements if I can.  I feel this is bit easier to read, but it's just my opinion.  I doubt there is any difference after it's compiled.