# Best way to build complex reports using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to do some dashboards and I am using LINQ to SQL to get a better performance than pull all data to memory.

The problem is that to do this, I cannot use methods (because linq to sql will not recognize methods to translate), so when I need a complex report, I need to repeat a lot of code and the code is becoming confuse.

One example:

[this is just to get the 5 more profit service orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huQ5L.png)

So, I think that probably I am doing this in a wrong way. Do you have suggestions to do a better code?

Thank you

Comment: Linq-to-SQL is a separate ORM which has been deprecated a long time ago. If you're using **Entity Framework**, then you'd be using **Linq-to-Entities** (not Linq-to-SQL) ....

Comment: You could do stored procedure, but I avoid those when possible. Better to do logic operations in code. So for something like this, I would generally grab the entity data up front and then process it into a view model. If the process requires additional database operations, you could use a tool like SignalR to provide status messages as it progresses.

Comment: Hi @marc_s , sorry, you must be right, I am confused about that linq to SQL and linq to entities.

Comment: Hi @SteveGreene You are right, I don't want to put logic operations in database. I am already using viewmodels, but the problem is the complexity of what I am want to get. I would like to use methods to not repeat code everytime

Comment: Like I said, go get your base data first, then compose your viewmodels where you can call methods. Otherwise, you can use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970100/calling-a-method-inside-a-linq-query) with `.AsEnumerable()` to use methods with LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Hi @SteveGreene thanks for your answer... I am thinking to do that(the technique) but the problem, I think, is that to get the 5 most profit projects, for example, I would need to enumerate all projects, right? This would need to get all project records to memory... I think could have a huge performance impact.

Comment: Depends. You can limit records on the server side with some sort of "Group By" operation if the record has the needed data to compute profit.